# Why my ubuntu image from Docker Hub ships with 4.19 Linux Kernel?

Tags: ubuntu, dockerhub

I'm using the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS image for various docker containers and recently realized, that they are running with the 4.19 linux kernel. I'm a bit curious why they are not running with the linux kernel 5.4 like mentioned in the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.17035449.1815140732.1599637731-352109589.1599637731). Anyone has an idea what went wrong?

Procedure to reproduce:

- docker pull ubuntu:latest
- docker run ubuntu:latest bash
- uname -r
- cat /proc/version
- cat /etc/os-release

Results:

```
uname -r 
4.19.76-linuxkit

cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.76-linuxkit (root@4abe09437d05) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Alpine 8.3.0)) #1 SMP Tue May 26 11:42:35 UTC 2020

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. Docker containers use the host kernel - they don't have their own.

Now, in your case, the fact it says `4.19.76-linuxkit` suggests that you're running on Windows or macos. They obviously don't have an underlying Linux kernel, so docker actually runs in a VM with a lightweight Linux OS (linuxkit). That's the kernel version you see.